# Using the call function with setTimeout in Javascript results in an illusive error

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project in which a huge task is broken down using timeouts. The function being called uses the `this` keyword, so I'd like to do something like this:

```
setTimeout(myObj.myFunction.call, 1000, myObj);
```

But this results in a super-strange unexpected error at line 1 of the webpage (making it **very** difficult for me to pin-point what was causing the error when it happened):

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

The error doesn't even get caught by a try/catch. Try it in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvc25vfe/1/).

Why does this happen? Is this my bug or a problem with Javascript? And is there a way to get my desired functionality short of passing in the scope object as a parameter to the called function?

Comment: Do `myObj.myFunction.bind(myObj)` instead. It's a common problem.

Comment: cf https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout `The "this" problem` »When you pass a method to setTimeout() (or any other function, for that matter), it will be invoked with a wrong this value. This problem is explained in detail in the JavaScript reference.«

Comment: @ThomasJunk Hello I understand the this problem and why it happens, which is why I'm using call. What I don't understand is why passing the call function into setTimeout breaks javascript. Also: What I am asking is explained in detail in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `setTimeout(function() {myObj.myFunction();}, 1000);`

Using an anonymous function makes it much more explicit what you're trying to do, and it should work better for it.

Comment: @skywalker No it wouldn't call it right away. The set timeout calls the function(){...} after 1000 ms. Bind also works, and so does passing a string into setTimeout (which is evil and so the answer is now gone, although I thought it was pretty cool :P).

Comment: It works if the call is wrapped in an anonymous function, `setTimeout(function(){ myObj.alertValue.call(myObj) }, 1000);`, example at https://jsfiddle.net/3rwava6g/

Comment: Agreed. I was responding to a line of comments that is now deleted. It's a shame that the other two answers to this question were also deleted. They both worked, although there was some misleading information in each.

Comment: They were not correct. One was wrong and one was using the questionable method of evaluating a string when run

Comment: What is wrong with using bind? I tried it and it worked. The eval method is not for best practices but it was still a legitimate, functional answer worth mentioning, and shouldn't have been censored just because someone thinks it's evil and doesn't want others to know of that functionality.

Comment: Bind is not compatible with older browsers.